# Step explain in Quantum Field Theory

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, operators, time-evolution

In my QFT homework, I am supposed to justify every step of a derivation. However, I'm confused about this step:

$$\langle u_b|\int_{-\infty}^0 dx_2 e^{i(H_0-E)x_2}e^{-\epsilon |x_1+x_2|}H_1  \dots \int^0_{-\infty} dx_n e^{i(H_0-E)x_n}e^{-\epsilon|x_1+\dots+x_n|} H_1|u_a\rangle \\ = e^{(n-1)\epsilon x_1}  \langle u_b| H_1 \int_{-\infty}^0 dx_2 e^{i(H_0-E)x_2}e^{(n-1)\epsilon x_2}H_1  \dots \int_{-\infty}^{0}dx_n e^{i(H_0-E)x_n}e^{\epsilon x_n}H_1| u_a\rangle
$$

I cannot see how the absolute value is removed. I tried in different ways, e.g. writing the last term's integral boundaries in terms of the sum of $x_1$ to $x_{n-1}$, but I still got confused. Can anyone show me why the step is correct? Notice $t$ may take any values and $x_1 \in (-\infty, t)$.

Comment: Please type out the specific step you’re confused about, using MathJaX.

Comment: I retyped your question to isolate the part you were asking about, hopefully this will make it more likely to be answered. I also simplified the notation, etc.